# Confused about Http verbs

Tags: wcf, http, rest, wcf-rest, http-verbs

I get confused when and why should you use specific verbs in REST?

I know basic things like:

```
Get -> for retrieval
Post -> adding new entity
PUT -> updating
Delete -> for deleting
```

These attributes are to be used as per the operation I wrote above but I don't understand why?
What will happen if inside Get method in REST I add a new entity or inside POST I update an entity? or may be inside DELETE I add an entity. I know this may be a noob question but I need to understand it. It sounds very confusing to me.

Comment: If you do that the REST police will come knocking at your door and make you read Roy Fielding's PHD thesis, and not just the chapter on REST. http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[@archil has an excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895729/confused-about-http-verbs/6896015#6896015) of the pitfalls of misusing the verbs, but I would point out that the rules are not quite as rigid as what you've described (at least as far as the protocol is concerned).

- GET MUST be safe.  That means that a GET request must not change the server state in any substantial way.  (The server could do some extra work like logging the request, but will not update any data.)
- PUT and DELETE MUST be idempotent.  That means that multiple calls to the same URI will have the same effect as one call.  So for example, if you want to change a person's name from "Jon" to "Jack" and you do it with a PUT request, that's OK because you could do it one time or 100 times and the person's name would still have been updated to "Jack".
- POST makes no guarantees about safety or idempotency.  That means you can technically do whatever you want with a POST request.  However, you will lose any advantage that clients can take of those assumptions.  For example, you could use POST to do a search, which is semantically more of a GET request.  There won't be any problems, but browsers (or proxies or other agents) would never cache the results of that search because it can't assume that nothing changed as a result of the request.  Further, web crawlers would never perform a POST request because it could not assume the operation was safe.

The entire HTML version of the world wide web gets along pretty well without PUT or DELETE and it's perfectly fine to do deletes or updates with POST, but if you can support PUT and DELETE for updates and deletes (and other idempotent operations) it's just a little better because agents can assume that the operation is idempotent.

See the [official W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for the real nitty gritty on safety and idempotency.

Comment: jhericks: Accepted your answer because it explained the verbs much much better. Thanks jhericks

Answer (score 4):

Protocol is protocol. It is meant to define every rule related to it. Http is protocol too. All of above rules (including http verb rules) are defined by http protocol, and the usage is defined by http protocol. If you do not follow these rules, only you will understand what happens inside your service. It will not follow rules of the protocol and will be confusing  for other users. There was an example, one time, about famous photo site (does not matter which) that did delete pictures with GET request. Once the user of that site installed the google desktop search program, that archieves the pages locally. As that program knew that GET operations are only used to get data, and should not affect anything, it made GET requests to every available url (including those GET-delete urls). As the user was logged in and the cookie was in browser, there were no authorization problems. And the result - all of the user photos were deleted on server, because of incorrect usage of http protocol and GET verb. That's why you should always follow the rules of protocol you are using. Although technically possible, it is not right to override defined rules.

Answer (score 2):

Using GET to delete a resource would be like having a function named and documented to add something to an array that deletes something from the array under the hood. REST has only a few well defined methods (the HTTP verbs). Users of your service will expect that your service  stick to these definition otherwise it's not a RESTful web service.

Answer (score 1):

If you do so, you cannot claim that your interface is RESTful. The REST principle mandates that the specified verbs perform the actions that you have mentioned. If they don't, then it can't be called a RESTful interface.